# json-api-dotnet filter attributes having null values using JSONAPI filter query parameters

Tags: json, filter, .net-core, query-string

In my solution, I have implemented a java client which consumes REST API implemented using JSONAPIDOTNETCORE.

Here is Java Code snippet which makes a call to REST API

```
      response = client
                    .resource(
                            CreateURLWithFilters(API_BASE_URL,
                                    "?page[size]=100&filter[endDate]=ge:"))
                    .accept("application/json")
                    .type("application/vnd.api+json")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token)
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

I am using filter query parameters supported by JSON API to get desired behaviour.

I would like JSON API to filter for a null value. For example

```
 "?page[size]=100&filter[endDate]=eq:null"
```

Not sure if JSONAPIDOTNET core library supports this kind of operation. Or could we implement filtering for null values inside jsonapidotnet core library.

For Example querying JSONAPI without filter parameters would give me this result

```
 [{"attributes":{"endDate":"2018-05-31T00:00:00","id":2,"priority":1,"message":"testing today ","propertyId":1,"roomId":null,"startDate":"2018-05-16T00:00:00","dateModifiedUtc":"2018-05-16T10:58:42.493"},"id":"2","type":"notices"}]
```

I would like to filter only those where enddate is null

```
[{"attributes":{"endDate":null,"id":1,"priority":1,"message":"wrewr","propertyId":1,"roomId":null,"startDate":"2018-05-16T00:00:00","dateModifiedUtc":"2018-05-16T10:38:22.727"},"id":"1","type":"notices"}
```